# Helper method not calling other helper method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, helper

I'm trying to break logic into a few separate chunks, but hitting a snag. The basic structure of my helper looks like:

```
({
    foo: function (component) {
        console.log(this.bar); // <-- undefined
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            this.bar(someValue);
        }, 12345);
    },
    bar: function (someArgument) {
        console.log("bar"); // <-- not called
    }
})
```

When I am in `foo`, why is `this.bar` undefined? Why does my timeout not call `bar`? If it is actually undefined, shouldn't I get an error for `undefined is not a function`? I tried inverting the order of the function definitions just to see if you can only call functions in this way if they are defined further up in the file, but it  did not change the behavior.

---

Turns out my initial example was overly simplified. What I actually had was more like:

```
foo: function (component, tabId) {
    // here is where I need to cache this
    component.find("workspaceAPI").getTabInfo({
        tabId: tabId
    }).then(function (response) {
        this.bar(someValue);
        // this no longer references the helper
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will run in a [Global Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and thus `this` will point to that context. To be able to utilize `this` in Function Context (which is `foo` in this case), you will need to assign the local context prior to calling `setTimeout` and then utilize it as below:

```
foo: function (component) {
    var myLocalThis = this; // capture the local context
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        myLocalThis.bar(someValue); // use the local context this here
    }, 12345);
},
```

Related Links:

- [MDN Docs for this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [Accessing 'this' variable in function passed to setInterval/setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571868/accessing-this-variable-in-function-passed-to-setinterval-settimeout)

Comment: A nice explanation for setTimeout "this" issues is available in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem). Personally, I'd use bind to set up a bound version of the function with the required this reference.